# scipy.spatial.Voronoi: How to know where a ray crosses a given line?

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

I have the following code segment:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

NUM_OF_POINTS = 20

points = []
for i in range (0, NUM_OF_POINTS):
    points.append([randint(0, 500), randint(0, 500)]) 

points = np.array(points)
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

That produces Voronoi plots such as this: [image: random Voronoi diagram]

My goal is to find where the 'rays' (the lines that go out of the plot, dashed or solid) intersect with a given line (for example x = 500). How may I go about doing this?

I have already tried using `ridge_vertices` list in the `Voronoi` object, however, these 'rays' are associated with only a single vertex in the list, so I cannot figure out the line equation.

My ultimate goal with this is, given the borders of the plane, to find the points that intersect with these borders for a given edge cell. For example, given the edge cell in the upper left, and the borders y = -50 and x = 525, I would find the points marked with the red X's.

[image: example case]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Corners are trivial because you know the x and the y coordinates.
2. The edges in a Voronoi diagram are equidistant to the centres of the two cells that are separated by that edge, which naturally includes the endpoint of a "ray" (in your terminology). Let the two centres be the points `(x1, y_1)` and `(x_2, y_2)`, and the intersection of the ray with the border be `(x*, y*)`, then the following holds:

(1) `(x*-x_1)^2 + (y*-y_1)^2 = d^2`

(2) `(x*-x_2)^2 + (y*-y_2)^2 = d^2`

You know either `x*` or `y*` because they are defined by the border. Then you have two equations, and two unknowns (`x*` or `y*` and `d`). Assuming you know `y*`, then you arrive at the following solution for `x*`:

`x* = ((y*-y_1)^2 - (y*-y_2)^2 + x_1^2 - x_2^2) / (2 * (x_1 - x_2))`

---

Now how do you figure out which pairs of points `(x_1, y_1)` and `(x_2, y_2)` to pick?

As a first pass, I would brute force it:

(1) Iterate over all combinations of points (n * (n-1) / 2 per border, so not that many), find `x*` or `y*`, respectively. That gives you a list `(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x*, y*)` of potential solutions.

(2) For each candidate `(x*, y*)` pair, I would find the 2 nearest neighbours in your original set of data points (efficiently via `scipy.spatial.KDTree`). If these points are not `(x_1, y_1)` and `(x_2, y_2)`, discard the candidate solution `(x*, y*)`.

Finding nearest neighbours in a KD-tree is O(n log n) (IIRC), so you are still O(n^2) for the whole procedure.

Comment: Though, given two regions, I don't know which of `x*` and `y*` I know, right? So I would have to compute for both cases and decide which one is applicable?

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what you mean. Could you elaborate? I thought you would set the boundaries?

Comment: I would, but how do I know which boundary a given ray crosses first, since it will possibly cross both?

Comment: Your rays cannot cross more than one boundary, provided that all data points are not collinear, i.e. on a straight line.

Comment: But the boundaries are defined as lines, not line segments. So the ray will eventually cross the second border after crossing the first one. I'm confused about how I can determine which one it crosses first - or if I can.

Comment: Fair point. However, the problem is easily fixed by only accepting solutions for x*/y* within the given boundaries.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.